# Why is removeClass is not working in this case?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

**JS:**

```
  $('.home-toggle').click(function() {
    scroll();
    $('#content twelvecol > a').removeClass('selected-tile');
    $(this).addClass('selected-tile');
    $('.hidden').hide();
    $('.home-container').slideDown();
  });

  $('.why-toggle').click(function() {
    scroll();
    $('#content twelvecol > a').removeClass('selected-tile');
    $(this).addClass('selected-tile');
    $('.hidden').hide();
    $('.why-container').slideDown();
  });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="content" class="container" style="display:none;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="twelvecol">
      <a href="#" class="home-toggle tile first">
        <img class="tile-top" src="images/tile1.png" alt="" />
        <img class="tile-bottom" src="images/tile1h.png" alt="" />
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="why-toggle tile">
        <img class="tile-top" src="images/tile2.png" alt="" />
        <img class="tile-bottom" src="images/tile2h.png" alt="" />
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="solutions-toggle tile last">
        <img class="tile-top" src="images/tile3.png" alt="" />
        <img class="tile-bottom" src="images/tile3h.png" alt="" />
      </a>
```

So `.selected-tile` should be removed from the other `.tile` once I click on one.

But for some reason, the class still remains in other tiles.

What could be the problem?

Comment: perhaps `scroll` throws an exception?

Answer (score 7):

You have a bug in your selector

```
$('#content twelvecol > a')
```

should be

```
$('#content .twelvecol > a')
//          ^ dot
```

Since the latter selects anchors that are top children inside of a container **with a class of** twelvecol, which is itself inside of an element with an id of `content`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not correct. Your are missing a dot for the `twelvecol` class.

Modify the below part, for both the click function's:

```
$('#content .twelvecol > a').removeClass('selected-tile');
```

Comment: It should be noted that the dot is missing from the _selector_.

Comment: Yes, missing a `.` in the selector. So, `removeClass` isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Not only the dot is missing, but also the `>` is missing. It should be:

```
$('#content > .row> .twelvecol > a');
```

`>` is only for child element, rather than grandchild.

So if you have:

```
<div id="a">
    <div class="b">
        <div class="c">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`$('#a > .c')` won't refer to the expected div. It should be `$('#a > .b > .c')` or `$('#a > div > .c')` instead.

See the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/S2JV3/1/

Comment: No.  `$('#content .twelvecol > a')` will work too (and is frankly cleaner), since the `.twelvecol` element is a descendant of `#content`.  Why add the > .row—it's superfluous noise?

Comment: @AdamRackis I was wrong. Thanks for that! I learned something new. =D

Comment: @Olivia - no problem.  Learning new things is what makes this site so amazing :-)